# Warning FitImage when running kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When run kivymd app I get:

```
[WARNING] [FitImage    ] Note!
In the near future the `FitImage` widget will be moved to the `kivymd.uix.fitimage` 
package.
Use import of this widget like this:`from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage`.
```

Why do I get this warning?

code link:
[Convert-toman-to-crypto-with-kivy](https://github.com/hialireza4/Convert-toman-to-crypto-with-kivy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning that the `FitImage` class in version `1.0.0` will be moved to the `kivymd.uix.fitimage package`.